# macro cannot be found or has been disabled. in ppt 2016

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

note - non duplicate: I have looked through the forums, ppt doesn't come up and all solutions given are reinstall or no solution.

I can not figure out how to let macros work on PPT. I write a macro in vba and it works until I close the document. It then no longer works on that document or any other, always throws the error in the heading. This happens for all macros.

I have enabled all setting, no security measure i could find was left on.

Tia

Comment: 1. After reopening the document, can you still see the source code you originally wrote? 2. Did you attempt to repair your Microsoft Office installation?

Comment: thanks, didn't know about repair. didin't help. yes, code is there

Comment: 3. Ensure that you are saving the file as *PowerPoint Macro-Enabled Presentation (\*.pptm)*. 4. Try moving the file to another computer. Will the macros work there? 5. Try moving similar macro file from another computer to your computer. Will the macros work?

Comment: I realize this is an old question but I just hit a wall with the same inscription and lost an hour over it. I was getting the message when **trying to run macros from a custom ribbon button** in a **newly** created presentation **based on a macro-enabled template** (notice the bold parts!). The solution no 3. by @miroxlav was the clue - to be able to run macros from the ribbon you **first have to save** the newly created presentation **as a macro-enabled presentation (.pptm)**.